# Parking Charge Calculation

Tags: c#, if-statement

SOLVED. Seriously thank you to everyone that had input. Fantastic community here.

I have an assignment where part of the program requires to figure out a parking charge for a customer.

Charges are based on hour and 1/2 hour increments.

Determine the number of hours and minutes. Minutes 1 through 30 are charged at 1/2 the hourly rate. Minutes from 31 through 59 are charged for a full hour.

Hourly charge is $2.00 per hour. There is no maximum time limit to park.

I am stuck on how to properly code this. I imagine it uses if-statements, which isn't a problem. But since there is no maximum time limit, I don't know how this would be coded properly, or how to at least get a start on it.

This is the code for my whole project so far, I just don't know how to start tackling this part of the program.

```
    public Waterpark()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void individualButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (groupNameTextBox.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                groupAmount = int.Parse(groupNameTextBox.Text);
                try
                {
                    parkingMinutes = int.Parse(parkedTextBox.Text);
                    IndividualTotals();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Must be an integer.", "INPUT ERROR");
                    parkedTextBox.Focus();
                    parkedTextBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Must be an integer.", "INPUT ERROR");
                peopleTextBox.Focus();
                peopleTextBox.SelectAll();
            }
        }
        else
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Must be a valid group name.", "INPUT ERROR");
          groupNameTextBox.Focus();
          groupNameTextBox.SelectAll();
        }    
    }


    private void eventOneCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventInt += 1;
        eventInt -= 1;
    }

    private void eventTwoCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventInt += 1;
        eventInt -= 1;
    }

    private void eventThreeCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventInt += 1;
        eventInt -= 1;
    }

    private void eventFourCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventInt += 1;
        eventInt -= 1;
    }

    private void eventFiveCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventInt += 1;
        eventInt -= 1;
    }

    private void IndividualTotals()
    {
        extraInt = eventInt - 1;

        switch(extraInt)
        {
        case 1:
            extraFee = 3.00;
            break;
        case 2:
            extraFee = 5.00;
            break;
        case 3:
            extraFee = 6.00;
            break;
        case 4:
            extraFee = 7.00;
            break;
        default:
            extraFee = 00.00;
            break;

        int hoursParked = minutesParked / 60;
        int minutesRemainder = hoursParked % 60;
        double hoursCost = hoursParked * 2;

        if (minutesRemainder <= 30)
        {
            minutesCost = 1;
        }

        else
        {
            minutesCost = 2;
        }
        parkingFee = hoursCost + minutesCost;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Added code I have so far. I just don't know how to specifically do this part.

Comment: You probably want to create a method called `CalculateParkingCharge` that returns a `decimal` and accepts the number of minutes a customer was parked as an input parameter. That's more clear than having a method called `IndividualTotals` that doesn't accept any parameters. It's not immediately clear to someone reading the code what `IndividualTotals` would do.

Comment: Ok, so how would I take 90 minutes for example, and return it as 1 hour and 30 minutes? I have the input textbox in my Design form for user input for parking minutes. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: If you do integer divison you can get the number of hours. If you use the % operator (modulus, that gets you the remainder) you can get the number of minutes (i.e. 90 % 60 = 30 / 60 = 0.5 hours).

Comment: The more I look at this question, the more I think "this is a perfect case for test driven development"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest to *separate* interface (buttons and text boxes to input data) from *logic*, which calculates fee. That'd be done by creating new method, that takes parameters (like hourly fee and total parking time) and returns total cost (just like *rsbarro* suggested). Then some button click event would only check correctness of input, call counting function, and put what it returns to some text box, whatever.

If I understand it correctly, the actual function counting the fee shouldn't be very difficult to write, if you consider how would you do it manually for person parking for example 20 mins, 30 mins, then 50, 60, 100, 200, 300, etc..

I'll write the rest based on this:

> Determine the number of hours and minutes. Minutes 1 through 30 are
>   charged at 1/2 the hourly rate. Minutes from 31 through 59 are charged
>   for a full hour.
>
> Hourly charge is $2.00 per hour. There is no maximum time limit to
>   park.

As this isn't very clear for me - should I charge 13 minutes as 13/30 of 1/2 hour rate, which would be ~$0.43, or is it $1, and 31 minutes is $2.00? Then 61 minutes would be $3.00 - and this is my interpretation.

1. **Determine the total number of minutes.**

   Consider how user gives input. One text box with minutes? Two text boxes with hours / minutes? One text box in *hh:mm* format? However it is, find way to count *total amount of minutes*, as this is what you base final fee on.
2. **Count**

   Since each 60 minutes would be charged $2.00, we can easily find number of hours by dividing number of minutes by 60 (or 61, depending on interpretation) and taking the quotient (its integer part). Which means:

   ```
   25 div 60 = 0
   35 div 60 = 0
   60 div 60 = 1
   95 div 60 = 1
   128 div 60 = 2
   ```

   Here we easily see, that in 25 and 35 minutes there is no full hour, while in 60 minutes there's one. In 128 minutes there are two full hours, for which we should charge our customer. This means that some *result value* (`rv`) would be `rv = (minutes / 60) * 2;`.

   Now we have to add fee for the remainder (not full hour). Here we have two options: if the remainder is less than 30, we charge only $1.00. If it's over 30, we charge the poor guy $2.00.
   You get remainder using `modulo` division:

   ```
   25 mod 60 = 25
   35 mod 60 = 35
   60 mod 60 = 0
   95 mod 60 = 35
   128 mod 60 = 8
   ```

   So, let's take `remainder = minutes % 60;`. And check the options (as it's your assignment, I'll write it in pseudo-code):

   ```
   remainder <- minutes mod 60;
   if remainder =< 30:
      add $1.00 to the fee
   else: # (if remainder is more than 30, namely 31..59)
      add $2.00 to the fee
   ```

After that it's only matter of returning total fee (fee for full hours + fee for remainder) by your function and presenting to the user.

Also out of curiosity: what are exactly `eventInt`'s in your code?

Comment: Input is one text box with minutes. Sorry, I should have been much more specific.

Comment: 13 minutes would be $1.00 and 31 minutes would be $2.00. The `eventInt` are variables to determine how many events our customer/user participated in. The program itself deals with a waterpark. Now, once we divide the total minutes by 60, how do we separate the quotient from the remainder?

Comment: You don't really *separate* quotient from the remainder. You *calculate* quotient like this `q = a / b`, and remainder like this: `r = a % b` (in `C#`). It's all in the answer...

As for the `eventInt`: I correctly assumed that it isn't considered when calculating parking fee then..

Comment: Nevermind, read your example over again. Making progress. My apologies.

Comment: There's a lot of text there, I agree, but I wanted to reproduce all my steps while solving the problem... Final code can be even an one-liner ;) And clear, simple solution can be easily fit in 5 lines

Answer (score 1):

I hate doing people's homework, but this one is really simple. You don't need an if statement at all.  Don't think of it as $2 per 60 min. Instead, it is $1 per 30 min. To get the number of 30-min increments, just divide the number of minutes the person parked by 30, and round up to the nearest int with `Math.Ceiling()`

It is actually a 1-liner:

```
[TestClass]
public class Parking
{
    private int GetParkingCharge(int minutesParked)
    {
        return (int)Math.Ceiling(minutesParked/30f);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestParking()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(0, GetParkingCharge(0));
        Assert.AreEqual(1, GetParkingCharge(25));
        Assert.AreEqual(2, GetParkingCharge(45));
        Assert.AreEqual(2, GetParkingCharge(60));
        Assert.AreEqual(3, GetParkingCharge(61));
        Assert.AreEqual(3, GetParkingCharge(90));
        Assert.AreEqual(4, GetParkingCharge(91));
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple to you is completely new to me. Appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound condescending. I meant that the problem was easier than you were making it out to be. I think you were probably over-complicating it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a sufficient algorithm for this:

```
public static float Charge(int lengthInMinutes)
    {
        float charge = 0.0f;
        while (lengthInMinutes >= 60)
        {
            charge += 2;
            lengthInMinutes -= 60;
        }

        // use this code instead of the 'if else' blog below to charge for ever minute after that for half the rate
        //float chargePerMinute = (float)((2.0f / 2) / 60);
        //charge += (float)lengthInMinutes * chargePerMinute;

        // at this point, we'll only have less than 60 minutes
        if (lengthInMinutes > 30)
        {
            charge += 2;
        }
        else if (lengthInMinutes > 0)
        {
            charge += 1;
        }
        if (charge > float.MaxValue)
            return float.MaxValue;
        return charge;
    }
```

Main function for testing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float charge = ParkingCharges.Charge(100);
        Console.WriteLine(charge.ToString("000.00"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Edit: Also, if your input is different (say you're getting a time class, or perhaps it's in a float form, simply transform it to minutes first)

Comment: I'm confused, but could also very well be a dumba**. But is your code Java? The `static void Main(string[] args)` screams Java at me. I only just started C#, so I'm not completely familiar.

Comment: @user1422051 no, it's run in C#. if you want my sample i can give it to you

Comment: If you want to hand out the sample, sure. I can use all the help I can on this.

Comment: That's shame you edited your answer removing previous code, it dealt with the other intepretation of the assigment... Also you don't need `float` now, and calculating `div` and `mod` is IMO more efficient than a loop (in this case)

Comment: @wasyl added it back in, regarding the float problem, the efficiency is negligible for parking calculations :P

Comment: @ChristopherBales I don't like the argument that efficiency 'is neglible in this case' ;) You know how to quickly do something a little bit better (without ruining half of your code and spending days on it), you do it ;)

Comment: @wasyl yes, I agree, but A. this is an example for what simply works and is easy to read for this case, and B. the float IS necessary for the previous code. certainly there are faster options....